# Combobox to be validate from data within a range

Tags: vba, combobox, lookup

I have a ComboBox5 - which I want to populate from an excel worksheet (FaultLog).  The values I wish to use are in Column B on the worksheet, but I only want them populated if Column O is blank.
Tried the code below!
I've created a range in the FaultLog sheet called "OpenFaults" but don't know how to filter the range.
Thanks in advance

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  Dim myfilter As String
  Dim cell As Range, Thisrow As Long, Lastrow As Long
  Worksheets(FaultLog).AutoFilterMode = False 'turns off
  myfilter = ""
  Range("OpenFault").AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:=myfilter
  ComboBox5.Clear
  'ComboBox1.RowSource = "TestMaterial"
  For Each cell In Range("OpenFault")
    Thisrow = cell.Row
    If Not cell.Rows.Hidden And Thisrow <> Lastrow Then
      ComboBox5.AddItem cell.value
    End If
    Lastrow = Thisrow
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO, Use Userform Initialize function to load combobox as below

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim cell As Range, OpenFaults As Range
    Set OpenFaults = YOURRANGE 'your values to be populated - range
    With Sheets("FaultLog")
        If Not WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("O:O")) = 0 Then
            For Each cell In OpenFaults
                ComboBox5.AddItem cell.Value
            Next
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi,  Thanks so much for the reply.  What do you mean by "YourRange".  Whatever 
I put in this value - I get a Type MisMatch error Thanks

Comment: Replace it with your range --> Range("OpenFault")